# vector of classes in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to fill vector of classes using the class constructor but I am getting compilation error:

> 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\file_io_and_main_argv\file_io_and_main_argv\file_io_argv.cpp(121):
>   error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal
>   conversion for 'this' pointer

The code I am using in the main program of C++ for Class Player is:

```
const vector<Player> players;  // vector list of players

  players.push_back(Player(ID,pname,WINS,LOSSES,POSX,POSY));  //insert player into vector of players
```

The error is on the point "." between players and push_back.

Comment: remove `const` ! `push_back` doesn't work when the instance is constant..

Answer (score 3):

Your `players` vector is declared as a `const`:

```
const vector<Player> players;
```

`const` means exactly that: constant. You can't change it. Can't `push_back()`, can't `erase()` existing elements in the vector, can't do anything to change the contents of the vector.

Remove the `const` keyword from the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify `const` vector. Remove `const` in `const vector<Player> players;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer you are right the const was the problem for some reason I found an example of code that they used the const and the compilation error does not help to figuare that...